# iOS Navigation Right Bar Button Item - icon changed after dialog

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have hamburger icon in Navigation bar set in Interface builder.

[image: Right bar button - Interface builder]

I have it in multiple controllers and everything looks ok. The problem is when I show alert dialog:

```
class func showSimpleAlert(parent:UIViewController, title:String, message:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    parent.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then icon is changed to this:

[image: Hamburger icon problem]

Why is that? Why I get that line there?

Size of my hamburger icon is 45 × 34 and I have it in Xcode Image Assets. Thanks for help

Comment: Did you see at the apple **iOS Human Interface Guide**, the **Icon and Image Size** section? 
(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1)

Could you give us access to your image?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problems.
Solution: Remove the "item" (Title field in your first picture) will help.

Comment: Three years later in an old project... `grep -nHr "\"Item\"" .` that did the trick. ^_^. I don't know why your answer has not been flagged as accepted. Btw, this appen only on iOS <= 10, in later version of iOS this occurs no more.